# for loop ignoring word length of 1

Tags: for-loop, splice

I'm working on this question:

> Write a function filterLongWords() that takes an array of words and an integer i and returns the array of words that are longer than i.

I have it down, except for some reason, if there is a word that is only one character long, it will not be deleted. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

```
function filterLongWords(i, array){
for (var x = 0; x<array.length; x++){
    if (array[x].length <= i){
        array.splice(x,x);
    }
}
console.log(array)
}

var wordArray = ["i", "am", "longer", "than", "one"];

filterLongWords(2, wordArray);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple problems here.

First, the arguments for `splice` are `(index, number of items)`, so you'll want to call
`array.splice(x,1)`

Second, when you remove an item from the array, the array is shortened but `x` will still advance (effectively skipping the next item). You can offset this with `x--;` after removing the item from the array.

```
function filterLongWords(i, array){
for (var x = 0; x<array.length; x++){
    if (array[x].length <= i){
        array.splice(x,1);
        x--;
    }
}
console.log(array)
}
```

Comment: You didnt change it to array.splice(x,1) in your example tho